# Almost same parameters for different function python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, if-statement, aws-cdk, optional-parameters

for example I have code as below:

```
if env = 'staging':
    db_cluster = rds.DatabaseCluster(self, 
                                     instances=2,
                                     identifier='ksdfjdsk', 
                                     region='string', 
                                     password='string',
                                     removal_policy='string'
                                     ... 
                                     ...
                                     iam='iam role name')

else:
    db_cluster = rds.DatabaseClusterFromSnapshot(self, 
                                                 instances=2,
                                                 snapshot_identifier="arn"
                                                 identifier='ksdfjdsk', 
                                                 region='string', 
                                                 password='string value',
                                                 removal_policy='stringsdfdd'
                                                 ... 
                                                 ...
                                                 iam='iam role name')
```

Here, `DatabaseCluster` and `DatabaseClusterFromSnapshot` are was-cdk APIs. Both take almost the same parameters and the only difference is `snapshot_identifier` extra parameter on second one.

Now the question is, Is there any method or logic so that I could reduce code blocks of if-else. (cause both have huge no.of parameters)

Comment: If they both only use keyword-arguments, then you can use dict-unpacking to call the function instead. Something like `someFunc(**dict_of_values)` where `dict_of_values` is something like `{"firstkw": "firstvalue", "secondkw": "secondvalue"}`

Comment: Okay got it.. thank you! I used dict-unpacking...

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is build a dictionary of the common arguments `common_args` like:

```py
common_args = dict(
    instances=2,
    region="string",
    identifier="ksdfjdsk",
    password="string",
    removal_policy="string",
    iam="iam role name",
)
```

Then use dictionary unpacking and `dict.update` (`|`) to add any required extra arguments to the specific call:

```
if env == "staging":
    db_cluster = rds.DatabaseCluster(self, **common_args)
else:
    extra_args = dict(snapshot_identifier="arn")
    db_cluster = rds.DatabaseClusterFromSnapshot(self, **(common_args | extra_args))
```

Comment: Thank you @tigs, You saved my day... Thank you so much again :)